# Python to convert different date formats in a column

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, date-formatting

I am trying to convert a column which has different date formats.

For example:

```
month
2018-01-01             float64
2018-02-01             float64
2018-03-01             float64
2018-03-01 00:00:00    float64
2018-04-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-05-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-06-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-07-01 01:00:00    float64
```

I want to convert everything in the column to just month and year. For example I would like Jan-18, Feb-18, Mar-18, etc.

I have tried using this code to first convert my column to datetime:

```
df['month'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['month'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

But it returns a float64:

Out

```
month
2018-01-01 00:00:00    float64
2018-02-01 00:00:00    float64
2018-03-01 00:00:00    float64
2018-04-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-05-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-06-01 01:00:00    float64
2018-07-01 01:00:00    float64
```

In my output to CSV the month format has been changed to 01/05/2016  00:00:00. Can you please help me covert to just month and year e.g. Aug-18.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

I assume you have a Pandas dataframe. In this case, you can use [`pd.Series.dt.to_period`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.to_period.html):

```
s = pd.Series(['2018-01-01', '2018-02-01', '2018-03-01',
               '2018-03-01 00:00:00', '2018-04-01 01:00:00'])

res = pd.to_datetime(s).dt.to_period('M')

print(res)

0   2018-01
1   2018-02
2   2018-03
3   2018-03
4   2018-04
dtype: object
```

As you can see, this results in a series of dtype `object`, which is generally inefficient. A better idea is to set the day to the last of the month and maintain a `datetime` series internally represented by integers.

Comment: Yes I have a Pandas dataframe. 

Unfortunately, your suggestion does not work for me. I get `ValueError: to assemble mappings requires at least that [year, month, day] be specified: [day,year] is missing`

Comment: A bit strange. I copied input data from your question. Can't help any further, I'm afraid, without accurate input data.

Comment: I believe input data is not of float type here as mentioned by OP in the question.